# Offset & Fetch Next will be ok to Use in a Loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, stored-procedures

I need to write a loop to pass data which are on a SQL temporary table to a stored procedure one by one. Is it OK to use the below approach? Does it cost lots of memory?

```
DECLARE @SomeData AS TABLE(
    Id      INT,
    Name    VARCHAR(MAX),
    Age     INT
)

INSERT INTO @SomeData
        ( Id, Name, Age )
VALUES  ( 1, 'AAAAA', 10 ),
        ( 2, 'BBBBB', 12 ),
        ( 3, 'CCCCC', 13 ),
        ( 4, 'DDDDD', 14 ),
        ( 5, 'EEEEE', 15 );

DECLARE @iterator INT = 0

WHILE @iterator< (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM @SomeData)
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM @SomeData
    ORDER BY Id 
    OFFSET @iterator ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY

    SET @iterator +=1


    /*Execute a Stored Procedure*/
END
```

Comment: this is a working query ?

Comment: @Squirrel- Yes it is working : https://imgur.com/a/DYKKX . also according to my knowledge this syntax only support after SQL Server 2012

Comment: Just use a cursor. They are designed for iterating through a table.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Thanks for the prompt reply, Ive heard that using a cursor is not recommend, since it eats more memory than While Loop.

Comment: Neither cursors or while loops are *recommended*. The preference is set based processing. But if you need to do it a cursor that starts off where it previously left off will be more efficient than your while loop that counts all rows on each iteration and then has to re-find its position from scratch each time.

Comment: http://bradsruminations.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/truth-about-cursors-part-1.html

Answer (score 3):

I think you don't need to (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM @SomeData) again after while, if table  SomeData is a big data it will slow. You can try like this:

```
DECLARE @iterator INT = 0
declare @n int = (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM @SomeData)
WHILE @iterator< @n
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM @SomeData
    ORDER BY Id 
    OFFSET @iterator ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY

    SET @iterator +=1


    /*Execute a Stored Procedure*/
END
```

Comment: Yeah, that's acceptable. But the real question is for me is not that Using the Query inside the Loop Will Cost more or not. Anyway, thanks for pointing that..