# REPLACE Too Slow Due to Full Table Scan

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I have an updated query to replace a part of string in a table will millions of rows. I have tried the following and its extremely slow I had to stop the query after 20 hrs. although it was working. Looking at execution's plan the majority of resources has been spent of Cluster Index update. My file factor on the index is zero. I would appreciate any suggestions

```
WHILE @sfCnt < = 10
    DECLARE @stringtoreplace varchar(50) = 'S:\Accounts\Share_' + LTRIM(str(@sfCnt)) + '\';

    UPDATE Accounts 
    SET DirPath = CASE
                      WHEN LEFT(Id, 2) IN ('00', '01')
                          THEN REPLACE (DirPath, @stringtoreplace, 'D:\Share\')
                      WHEN LEFT(Id, 2) IN ('16', '17')
                          THEN REPLACE (DirPath, @stringtoreplace, 'E:\Share\')
                      WHEN LEFT(Id, 2) IN ('80', '92')
                          THEN REPLACE (DirPath, @stringtoreplace, 'F:\Share\')
                      WHEN LEFT(Id, 2) IN ('c0', 'c1')
                          THEN REPLACE (DirPath, @stringtoreplace, 'G:\Share\')
                      WHEN LEFT(Id, 2) IN ('07', '08')
                          THEN REPLACE (DirPath, @stringtoreplace, 'H:\Share\')
                  END

    SET @sfCnt = @sfCnt + 1
END
```

Comment: this will never work, as with every iteration you let the update run over and over again with all rows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Offset & Fetch Next will be ok to Use in a Loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46482044/offset-fetch-next-will-be-ok-to-use-in-a-loop)

Comment: This is why (when storing file-paths) you should have a dbo.RootDirectory table.  And put in values like 'S:\Accounts\' and 'D:\Share\'  this table would have like <100 rows.  then your millions of rows table would FK to this table (RootDirectory) with the "suffix" part of the filename.  And your final value would be the composite of these 2.  THEN when the millions of files get moved....you can do more of a "meta-change" on dbo.RootDirectory ... vs string-replacing a million rows.  That's my IMHO advice for a small design.

Comment: There's *definitely* a `BEGIN` missing after the `WHILE` - if you want to have multiple statements run inside that block of the `WHILE` clause - you **must** use a `BEGIN` (and you also already have an `END` which also indicates at a missing `BEGIN`)

Comment: Updates on a clustered index means a reoganisation of the data, this is a lot of I/O operation. The loop don't seem to make much sense either.